# python requests post returning weird characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-requests

I am trying to send a post requests to an api endpoint which is supposed to return json . however i am getting weird characters. I tried to encode with utf-8 but without success.

```
import requests

url1= "https://cliff.mediacloud.org/process"

header ={"accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-DZ;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7",
"content-length": "56",
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"cookie": "__cfduid=d90785d2f72bf656c19e794239e26185d1585929126; _ga=GA1.2.1927368988.1585929126; _gid=GA1.2.61609766.1585929126 ; _gat_gtag_UA_60744513_13=1",
"origin": "https://cliff.mediacloud.org",
"referer": "https://cliff.mediacloud.org/",
"sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
"sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
"sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36",
"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"}

text1 = "i am traveling to france"

data1={"text": text1,
"demonyms": "false",
"language": "EN"}

r = requests.post(url=url1, headers=header, data=data1 )

print (r.text)
```

Any clue on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the *br* in *accept-encoding*

```
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
```

Request Result will look like this

```
{"milliseconds": 3, "language": "EN", "version": "2.6.1", "results": {"places": {"mentions": [{"featureCode": "PCLI", "featureClass": "A", "confidence": 1.0, "lon": 2.0, "countryGeoNameId": "3017382", "source": {"charIndex": 18, "string": "france"}, "population": 64768389, "stateGeoNameId": "", "countryCode": "FR", "name": "Republic of France", "stateCode": "00", "id": 3017382, "lat": 46.0}], "focus": {"cities": [], "countries": [{"score": 1, "featureCode": "PCLI", "stateGeoNameId": "", "featureClass": "A", "countryCode": "FR", "name": "Republic of France", "lon": 2.0, "countryGeoNameId": "3017382", "stateCode": "00", "id": 3017382, "lat": 46.0, "population": 64768389}], "states": []}}, "organizations": [], "people": []}, "status": "ok"}
```

Comment: This works for me, but I still want to know how this works! can you please explain how removing be fixes the issue @Jens

Comment: First: I have no clue, just did try and error to solve the problem . After some googeling: "br" stands for Brotli algorithm. This comes wirth urllib3 but is not installed by default. So I guess the webserver delivers the response encoded in brotli but you environment is missing the brotil package. Maybe try "pip install brotli" or brotlipy