# requests.request.text returns encoded symbols

Tags: python, json, postman, httpresponse

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://node1.web3api.com/"

payload = json.dumps({
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 2,
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "data": "0xc87b56dd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d2",
            "to": "0x792496a3f678187e59e1d1d5e075799cd1e124c2"
        },
        "latest"
    ]
})
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://etherscan.io/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://etherscan.io',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'TE': 'trailers'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

> the print statement prints the following:
> ��D��R���Ӥ����?l��`�I ��h��'���x=Ϥ�d3��rϚ�^��@�S�D���Ė��s��"�TZL�yeyD�gfT"*���H��'(GD��k,`�XQ��fK4f+�

> I tried this instead:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://node1.web3api.com/"

payload = json.dumps({
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 2,
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "data": "0xc87b56dd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d2",
            "to": "0x792496a3f678187e59e1d1d5e075799cd1e124c2"
        },
        "latest"
    ]
})
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://etherscan.io/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://etherscan.io',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'TE': 'trailers'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print("ENCODING: ", response.encoding)
print(response.json())
```

> This second implementation returns the following error:

```
ENCODING: utf-8

requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] ��D��R���Ӥ����?l��`�I ��h��'���x=Ϥ�d3��rϚ�^��@�S�D���Ė��s��"�TZL�yeyD�gfT"*���H��'(GD��k,`�XQ��fK4f+�: 0
```

> ultimately, I should be receiving the following response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a697066733a2f2f516d564c62664470426a3958785843436757776873687041514539583233736b5a3853667055506e323948686e512f31323334000000000000"}
```

> I know that this is the response I should be getting because it is the response I get when I make the request within the browser, as well as within Postman. I am simply attempting to make the same HTTP request via python.

> What should I do to decode the response?

Comment: Can you share how you got to know that the decoded response should be the json you mentioned in the last

Comment: The HTTP request was grabbed from an action carried out on FireFox. I imported the HTTP request into Postman, which returns the HTTP response I submitted above. However, when I try to implement the request in python, I receive an encoded message, even though the encoding is utf-8.

Comment: solved my issue via this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031952/python-requests-post-returning-weird-characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the output. One way of doing this is using [decodeParameters()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameter) from web3.js

1. Initialising web3 (following the official Ethereum docs from [here](https://ethereum.org/fr/developers/tutorials/set-up-web3js-to-use-ethereum-in-javascript/),

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://cloudflare-eth.com");
```

2. Next, we need to specify how the decoded JSON would be like.
   We must mention the datatype (**of Solidity**) and the name of the params.

```
// Example, if JSON is like this, then typesArray should be
// {
//   id: "125325645",
//   name: "Captain America"
// }

const typesArray = [
  { type: 'uint8', name: 'id' },
  { type: 'string', name: 'name' }
];
```

3. Call the decodeParameters() function with the decoded string

```
const res = await web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(typesArray, decodedString);
```

The `res` will be of the following type:

```
{
  '0': '125325645',
  '1': 'Captain America',
  __length__: 2,
  id: "125325645",
  name: "Captain America"
}
```

**Extras:**
If your expected JSON has nested elements, then you will need to use `components` and this is how you declare your `typesArray`,

```
// Example JSON:
// {
//   people: [
//     {
//       id: '453545',
//       name: 'Captain America',
//     },
//     {
//       id: '567567',
//       name: 'Iron Man',
//     }
//   ]
// }

const typesArray = [
  {
    type: 'tuple',
    name: 'people',
    components: [
      { type: 'uint8', name: 'id' },
      { type: 'string', name: 'name' }
    ]
  }
];
```